# Sublime Text - Find Class Name

Tags: sublimetext

I am looking for anyone who has found a way to select class or id names for html tags.

Sublime Text can do so many things I just can't believe that there is no package to find the names or ID's.

```
<p class="classname"></p>
```

There has to be something

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have figured this out sort of, only for for class names and not ID's.

Got to the link below, save the text using the python extension (.py) in your packages directory and you should be good to go.

https://gist.github.com/icebeat/5804902